# Why did the builders install 5 2x4s together behind drywall?

Tags: drywall, walls, framing

Trying to mount some shelving in my garage and based on images before drywall was installed, the builders installed multiple 2x4s at certain points in the wall. The only thing that I can think of is that there is a outdoor spigot on the other side of this wall.

I was wondering why the builders would install 5 2x4s seated together at this particular point, and more importantly, **can I mount some shelving by drilling into the studs?[image]**

Comment: Directly across the garage there is probably an identical set of five studs, and these two posts support a horizontal beam running across the garage. The ceiling joists are probably attached to the beam with nails and joist hangers

Comment: The holes for the pipe/cable do more harm to the studs and are perfectly okay.  A brunch of screws do much less harm, except where the cable/pipe is.  You do not want to screw into pipe/cables.

Comment: Is there living space above this garage?

Comment: These groups of studs are called "stud packs" and used for supporting loads above

Answer (score 8):

**Look up.** Usually that would be supporting a beam above.

So long as you stay out of the area where the protective plates are for the waterline, you can mount shelf brackets to it.